# Terminating a recursive function in C

Tags: c, recursion, binary-tree

```
int postOrder(struct node* root, char organ[], char bt[], int* val){

    if(root != NULL) {
        postOrder(root->left, organ, bt, val);
        postOrder(root->right, organ, bt, val);
        if(strcmp(root->organ.organname, organ) == 0){
            if(strcmp(root->organ.bloodtype, bt) == 0){
               if(val == 0){
                printf("%s\n", root->organ.name);
                val = 1;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to terminate this recursive function right after the first print. My idea originally was to pass in a decimal pointer 'val' and set that to 1 when I wanted to terminate the function. The thought process is it would change the value outside of the function so all of the previous calls would have the updated pointer, but I don't think that's how it works in this setup.

This function searches post the Post Orderly through a binary tree.

Comment: You don't have a `return` in a statement that returns a value.  You don't test the value (not yet) returned by the function, which presumably you would need to do: `if (postOrder(root->left, organ, bt, val) != XXX && postOrder(root->right, organ, bt, val) != XXX) { ...test this node... }` for a suitable value of XXX returned by the function indicating that it found the value you are looking for.  Or you could make the function return `void` and test `*val` before calling recursively, or testing the current node.

Answer (score 5):

Use `*val`.
val is just a pointer. You want the value of it.

Comment: This seems to be crashing the program -- I assume you mean *val = 1;

Comment: @RJones If this crashes the program, then you are doing something terribly, inherently bad. Use a debugger. And even before you use a debugger: read a good elementary level C book.

Comment: @H2CO3 "something" likely means "not passing a valid pointer to an `int` to the top-level invocation :-)

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Evidently :)

Comment: @H2CO3 I definitely do need to read up some more, I'm still very new

Answer (score 1):

Since currently your function does not return anything, you can change it to return `1` if it has printed anything, and return `0` if it does not. This way you wouldn't need to pass `val` pointer (which you are not using correctly anyway).

```
int postOrder(struct node* root, char organ[], char bt[]){
    if(root == NULL)  return 0;
    if (postOrder(root->left, organ, bt, val)) return 1;
    if (postOrder(root->right, organ, bt, val)) return 1;
    if (strcmp(root->organ.organname, organ) == 0 && strcmp(root->organ.bloodtype, bt) == 0) {
        printf("%s\n", root->organ.name);
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This worked, thank you. Now comes the task ahead of me finding out why I couldn't think of this myself. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @RJones You are welcome! Recursion takes some getting used to - don't worry, two to three exercises later you will be coming up with solutions like that without thinking twice.

Answer (score 0):

val is a pointer to an integer so you will need to dereference it when setting or getting its value.

Try:

`if(*val == 0) {
       *val = 1;
...
    }`